# Graphical Dyslexia -- building intuition for common data visualizations?

Tags: visualization

It took me years before I could understand what was going on in a histogram. I had trouble understanding the tails, skewness, and concepts such as "fat tails."

With a lot of practice, histograms have become more intuitive for me.

I believe I have some sort of "graphical dyslexia."

I want to build an inituitive understanding of basic, common types of data visualizations such as:

- histograms
- scatter plots
- dotplots
- stem and leaf plots
- density plots

By intuitive, I mean that when I glance at one of these plots, I want to figure out the gist of it within a few seconds (rather than stare at it for minutes without anything registering in my mind, ***as is usually the case for me***).

StackExchange: can you recommend to me books/resources that can help me with this?

Comment: _understanding of all kinds of data visualizations_ makes this question very broad, as there are 100s of types of viz. So, pl consider narrowing your down, or breaking this question into multiple seperate questions.

Comment: @Dawny33 Thanks, appreciate the pointers. I've edited my question, hope it suffices... otherwise feel free to give me more pointers.

Answer (score 4):

There are two books that are our "bibles" in data visualisation.

- Edward Tufte, [The Visual Display of Quantitative Information](https://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Visual-Display-Quantitative-Information/dp/0961392142?ie=UTF8&qid=1461059964&ref_=la_B000APET3Y_1_1&s=books&sr=1-1)
- David McCandless [Information is Beautiful](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Information-Beautiful-New-David-McCandless-x/dp/0007492898/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1461060112&sr=1-1&keywords=data%20is%20beautiful)

Tufte has a wealth of examples on good and bad visualisations. McCandless has some lovely, or even beautiful graphics and ways to display data.